# Merge duplicated rows that have different values into multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data where there are essentially 3 values per sample.

It's provided as a rowise table like the below example:

```
Well    Drug    Drug_Conc   
A1       D1       0.5
A1       D2       0.25
A1       D3       0.1
```

The problem is if a drug is not put into a well, it doesn't have a row in the dataset. So for example, if  well B1 has only D1 and D2, they rows for B1 will be as follows:

```
Well    Drug    Drug_Conc   
B1       D1       0.5
B1       D2       0.25
```

What I want to do is get something like this:

```
Well   Drug1_conc   Drug2_conc   Drug3_conc
A1          0.5         0.25          0.1
B2          0.5         0.25          0
```

Is something like this possible?

I'm thinking I have to create a new dataframe that has a single row for each well, as well as 3 columns of zeroes for each drug. I'm a bit lost what to do after though.

Answer (score 1):

We can easily do this with `pivot_wider`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- structure(list(Well = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "B1", "B1"), Drug = c("D1", 
"D2", "D3", "D1", "D2"), Drug_Conc = c(0.5, 0.25, 0.1, 0.5, 0.25
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df1 %>% pivot_wider(
  names_from = Drug, 
  names_glue = "{sub('.*(\\\\d+).*', 'Drug\\\\1_Conc', Drug)}",
  values_from = Drug_Conc, values_fill = 0)


# A tibble: 2 × 4
  Well  Drug1_Conc Drug2_Conc Drug3_Conc
  <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 A1           0.5       0.25        0.1
2 B1           0.5       0.25        0
```

Comment: Thank you this helped! One question I have is I can't manage to get this working without using structure. Is there any reason to use that specifically? Or is it because the dataframe has other data in it that's not relevant (like timestamps and such)

Comment: Note that `rename_if()`, `rename_at()`, and `rename_all()` have been superseded by `rename_with()`.

Comment: You can also add `names_glue = "{sub('.*(\\\\d+).*', 'Drug\\\\1_Conc', Drug)}"` into `pivot_wider()` to avoid `rename()`.

Comment: @LinearParadox `structure` is just creating a sample data frame to run my proposed solution on. What sort of error are you getting? If you have additional columns in the real data, you need to consider whether the columns need to be excluded all together, or included as `id_cols` in the `pivot_wider` statement. For instance, if you have a timestamp column that is different for each row, that column won't neatly aggregate when you pivot. If it's the same for each Well, then you can add it in `id_cols`.

Comment: And nice solution for the names @DarrenTsai, I've updated my answer based on it.